# Xamarin OAuth2Authenticator Microsoft Account returns malformed JWT token for Azure App Service

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, xamarin.auth, microsoft-account

I am building a Xamarin.Forms app to learn the framework and working on the authentication services while using an Azure App Service for an API (also new to me). And trying to authenticate against a Microsoft account (Outlook.com).

I am using the Xamarin.Auth OAuth2Authenticator class and it is returning a very peculiar, malformed JWT token. This has been driving me nuts for days and finally decided to turn to where the experts are.

I have an IAuthService interface that will be used by the platform apps to build out the authentication service

```
public interface IAuthService
{
    Task SignInAsync(string clientId,
    Uri authUrl,
    Uri callbackUrl,
    Action<string> tokenCallback,
    Action<string> errorCallback);
}
```

Said service (for iOS) is built out as follows (shortened for brevity):

```
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    public async Task SignInAsync(string clientId, Uri authUrl, Uri callbackUrl, Action<string> tokenCallback, Action<string> errorCallback)
    {
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId, "openid", authUrl, callbackUrl);
        auth.AllowCancel = true;

        var controller = auth.GetUI();

        await UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewControllerAsync(controller, true);

        auth.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            controller.DismissViewController(true, null);

            if (e.Account != null && e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Account.Properties["access_token"]);

                tokenCallback?.Invoke(e.Account.Properties["access_token"]);
            }
            else
            {
                errorCallback?.Invoke("Not authenticated");
            }
        };
      ...
    }
}
```

So I instantiate a new instance of the OAuth2Authenticator class, specifying the scope as "openid"; the MS authorize endpoint requires a scope.

When it hits the console writeline I can see a value came back... but it's not like any JWT token I have seen before.

```
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
```

It's not encoded/decoded.

The authUrl I am using is
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
If I attempted to use the v1.0 of the authorize endpoint, the phone OS appears to throw an error to me stating Authentication Error - Invalid state from server. Possible forgery!

I have set up an Azure App Service to act as my API and if I hit my app login url directly it gives me back a well formed token which I then could use to hit the api with no problem. So that tells me that my cliend_id are correct and everything should work.

So I am doing it wrong somewhere. I don't know if I trust the OAuth2Authenticator class from Xamarin when using MS accounts. But documentation is old and/or lacking. I feel like it's going to be an easy answer but I am going cross-eyed trying to interpret MS/Xamarin/Googled documentation.